# In "The Lobster" how much of original human mind is left after transformation?

Tags: plot-explanation, the-lobster

In The Lobster (Yorgos Lanthimos, 2015) people who can't find a romantic pair in 45 days are transformed into animals. There is a transformation room where supposedly people are transformed.. [image] But the details mentioned are only rumours and the actual procedure is kept secret. Is there any clue in the movie indicating whether any of the original human characteristics are transferred to the animal? For instance, the Colin Farrell's dog shows any sign of being his brother? I wonder how much of human could be transfered into a lobster.. none of it I suppose.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there any clue in the movie indicating whether any of the original human characteristics are transferred to the animal?

The only characteristic that's hinted at in the film is compassion/love.

At one point, The Limping Man comments about how his parents were turned into wolves and then later placed in captivity. He eventually goes to visit them and tries to determine which of the wolves are his parents by jumping in the cage with all the other wolves, with the idea that his parents wouldn't attack him. There were in fact two wolves that didn't attack him, which he then believed to be his parents.

Of course, this is a [relatively] completely arbitrary and non-reliable way of trying to determine if any of those wolves were really his parents. However, again, this is the only time that a characteristic of a person with respect to after they've been transformed into an animal is mentioned.

In my opinion though, after giving the film much thought and consideration since I've seen it, I don't believe the people are actually turned into animals.

Comment: Isn't the dog the main character's brother?

Comment: @ChronoTrigger Yes... not seeing what your point is though. The OP asked in general if the film depicts any transferred characteristics, and then suggested the possibility of the David's brother as a dog showing any signs. The question though wasn't specifically asking about David's dog, though, I did still indirectly address this by stating that the only possible indication of transferred characteristics was with The Limping Man's parents as wolves.

Comment: I overlooked OP's comment about the main character's dog and focused on you don't believing people are actually turned into animals. To me, that observation was clearly false because of the dog, but now I understand that's the point of the discussion.

Comment: @Charles: I am afraid your recollection of the movie is a bit sketchy. There were indeed two wolves, who refrained from attacking the limping man, but only one of them was (believed) to be his parent (mother). There is no information given about his father, but since his mother went to the hotel, he was most likely out of the picture. "My mother entered the hotel, but didn't make it and was turned into a wolf. I really missed her.". My interpretation would rather be that random facts get overexaggerated into an emotion. Maybe none of the wolves was his mother and they simply were not hungry.